# Easy way to sort DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm really new to JS and i'm trying to sort this code from the higher user_mmr to lowest.

```
    <table>
    <tr class="user"><td class="user_name">Kyun#294</td><td class="user_mmr">4837</td>
<tr class="user">
<td class="user_name">MiR#350</td>
<td class="user_mmr">4143</td>
```

There's any way to do something like that?

Comment: Transform the dom nodes into an object or put them in an array and sort em and output them again ?

Comment: Easiest way is to use jQuery Data Tables. [DataTable](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sort a HTML Table</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to sort the table, by score:</p>
  <p><button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button></p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Andam</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ali</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Akam</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function sortTable() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");;
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
      var currentRow;
      var nextRow;

      for (var i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j < rows.length - 1; j++) {
          currentRow = rows[j].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
          nextRow = rows[j + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
          if (Number(currentRow.innerHTML) < Number(nextRow.innerHTML)) {
            rows[j].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[j + 1], rows[j]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A naive bubble sort performing swaps in the DOM will _not_ scale well. In a nearly completely unscientific test, my browser took over 5 seconds to sort a table with 400 rows.

Comment: He said easy not best way. He did not mention why he needs it. Maybe it's just a school project.

Comment: I would argue that implementing your own sorting algorithm doesn't rate highly by either the "easy" or "good" metrics. And if it's a school project, throwing out a solution with no explanation of how it works or why it's good doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Why dont we leave that part for him.

Comment: Thanks Andam, isn't a project for school, is just a personal project the i'm doing :)